# Can Ubuntu One be used to deploy a cloud?

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install LAMP server on Ubuntu One private cloud?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116404/can-i-install-lamp-server-on-ubuntu-one-private-cloud)

I'm new to Ubuntu operating system and just want to know whether **Ubuntu one** can be used as a cloud machine (eg.Deploying on cloud machine, Testing on cloud, etc) or it's just a file storage space given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am wrong, I believe that `Ubuntu One` is just like a `Dropbox`. It is a file storage service. In other words, just like you said, it is just a file storage space given. You can read more about `Ubuntu One` by clicking on the link below:

http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/features/ubuntu-one

Now, if you are interested in starting your own cloud, you can do it with `Ubuntu Server`. Here is more reading on that subject. Click the link below:

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud

Hope this answers it.

Comment: Does it allow hotlinking or any bandwidth limit?

Comment: Ubuntu One is not just like dropbox, but it is not a cloud computing service either. It's a data synchronization/access service; more than simple storing/syncing of regular files.

Answer (score 0):

No. UbuntuOne is a could personal files storage system, it will not run the services for you.
A better option for you is really use something like Amazon EC2 instance and have your services running there. Ubuntu can deploy and configure that on the fly using [Juju Charms](https://juju.ubuntu.com/).